# Not delete In/Outbound file after Monitor() CMD in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I'm recording call via Monitor() Command.
When this command is running i can see two different files (Filename-in.wav and Filename-out.wav) and when Monitor() command is finished it mix those two file and merge them to one  (Filename.wav) file.

So the problem is that i want to keep both file after Monitor Cmd Execution but i didn't found a way to do it.
So after the final execution of the Monitor command i will have three file not only one

```
Ex:
Filename-in.wav
Filename-out.wav
Filename.wav (the mixed one with outbound and inbound voice
```

So is there any body who can give me an easy solution

Comment: What version of Asterisk?  Are you using FreePBX or PIAF or another UI front-end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom script for mixmonitor. In that script you can do whatever you want, including files like you described.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/MixMonitor

Note, that in Filename.wav you have both inbound and outbound in different channels. So you can easy got inbound only by mute left channel and outbound only by mute right channel.

Comment: i'm trying to found a solution with Monitor() App.
I don't want to Filename.wav after just to get to file as you sad, i wanna that Monitor() do it for me from the beginig. way wasting cpu two time for the same thing ?

I think that i found a solution and if it will work i will post it here.

Comment: MixMonitor have script param exactly for task like you asked. Just create your own mixing script.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to change the code of the res_monitore.c and recompile it again.

This is the portion of code that delete the raw file

```
00295          if (delfiles) {
00296             snprintf(tmp2,sizeof(tmp2), "( %s& rm -f \"%s/%s-\"* ) &",tmp, dir ,name); /* remove legs when done mixing */
00297             ast_copy_string(tmp, tmp2, sizeof(tmp));
00298          }
```

Just we have to add this { delfiles = 0; }in line 00294

```
00294          delfiles = 0;
00295          if (delfiles) {
00296             snprintf(tmp2,sizeof(tmp2), "( %s& rm -f \"%s/%s-\"* ) &",tmp, dir ,name); /* remove legs when done mixing */
00297             ast_copy_string(tmp, tmp2, sizeof(tmp));
00298          }
```

I changed delfiles = 0 to force the function to not remove the file.

```
After that this is the command that you have to type :

cd /usr/src/asterisk-1.8.23.0
make
cp  ./res/res_monitor.so /res/res_monitor.so.backup
cp  ./res/res_monitor.so /usr/lib/asterisk/modules
/etc/ini.d/asterisk restart
```

and u keep using the Monitor() command as before with the functionality that keep the raw file (Filename-in.wav and Filename-out.wav and of course Filename.wav)

Comment: Modify asterisk source for task which can be done without modification is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

What arheops did not understand in that conversation is that the "command" argument is executed after the "in" and "out" legs have been mixed by (Mix)Monitor.

There is no other way to save the "receive" and "transmit" feeds than to either change the source code as l3on1das suggested (not good practice though), or upgrade to Asterisk 11+, which now (not surprisingly) supports the options -t and -r for MixMonitor() to respectively save the transmitted and received legs in addition to the mixed output.

Good luck to anyone digging in asterisk for speech segmentation.